# blueimp jQuery File Upload Multiple Instance

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to implement blueimp ajaxfile uploader in ASP.Net website

[Blueimp JQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

I was able to implement the uploader successfully apart from customizing some css due to space constraint.

Now my actual requirement is to implement multiple instances of this control on this same asp.net page.

If some one had tried to implement multiple instance of Blueimp JQuery File Upload for ASP.Net on same page please help me on this issue.

Below is main portion of code I am using to add the control in the page

```
<div id="fileupload">
<form action="Handler.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
    <label class="fileinput-button">
        <span>Add files...</span>
        <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
        <input id="hdnFundID" name="hdnFundID" value="1236" type="hidden" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="start">
        Start upload</button>
    <button type="reset" class="cancel">
        Cancel upload</button>
    <button type="button" class="delete">
        Delete files</button>
</div>
</form>
<div class="fileupload-content">
    <table class="files">
    </table>
    <div class="fileupload-progressbar">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<tr class="template-upload{{if error}} ui-state-error{{/if}}">
    <td class="preview"></td>
    <td class="name">${name}</td>
    <td class="size">${sizef}</td>
    {{if error}}
        <td class="error" colspan="2">Error:
            {{if error === 'maxFileSize'}}File is too big
            {{else error === 'minFileSize'}}File is too small
            {{else error === 'acceptFileTypes'}}Filetype not allowed
            {{else error === 'maxNumberOfFiles'}}Max number of files exceeded
            {{else}}${error}
            {{/if}}
        </td>
    {{else}}
        <td class="progress"><div></div></td>
        <td class="start"><button>Start</button></td>
    {{/if}}
    <td class="cancel"><button>Cancel</button></td>
</tr>
</script>
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<tr class="template-download{{if error}} ui-state-error{{/if}}">
    {{if error}}
        <td></td>
        <td class="name">${namefdsa}</td>
        <td class="size">${sizef}</td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2">Error:
            {{if error === 1}}File exceeds upload_max_filesize (php.ini directive)
            {{else error === 2}}File exceeds MAX_FILE_SIZE (HTML form directive)
            {{else error === 3}}File was only partially uploaded
            {{else error === 4}}No File was uploaded
            {{else error === 5}}Missing a temporary folder
            {{else error === 6}}Failed to write file to disk
            {{else error === 7}}File upload stopped by extension
            {{else error === 'maxFileSize'}}File is too big
            {{else error === 'minFileSize'}}File is too small
            {{else error === 'acceptFileTypes'}}Filetype not allowed
            {{else error === 'maxNumberOfFiles'}}Max number of files exceeded
            {{else error === 'uploadedBytes'}}Uploaded bytes exceed file size
            {{else error === 'emptyResult'}}Empty file upload result
            {{else}}${error}
            {{/if}}
        </td>
    {{else}}
        <td class="preview">
            {{if Thumbnail_url}}
                <a href="${url}" target="_blank"><img src="${Thumbnail_url}"></a>
            {{/if}}
        </td>
        <td class="name">
            <a href="${url}"{{if thumbnail_url}} target="_blank"{{/if}}>${Name}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size">${Length}</td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    {{/if}}
    <td class="delete">
        <button data-type="${delete_type}" data-url="${delete_url}">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="example/jquery.iframe-transport.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="example/jquery.fileupload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="example/jquery.fileupload-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="example/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**application.js** (pasted from author's comment)

```
$(function () 
{ 
  'use strict'; 
  // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget: 
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({ }); 
  $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) { ...... }); 
  // Open download dialogs via iframes, 
  // to prevent aborting current uploads: 
  $('#fileupload .files a:not([target^=_blank])').live('click', function (e) 
  { 
    e.preventDefault(); ....... 
  }); 
});
```

Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

This was answered by blueimp himself. Have a look here:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Upload-Widgets-on-the-same-page

So, you need a form for each upload and separate templates which you can pass references on initialization.

**1** 
give each form the same class, e.g. 'fileupload'

**2**
initialize them all with

```
$('.fileupload').each(function () {
  $(this).fileupload({
      dropZone: $(this)
  })
  .bind('fileuploaddone', function(){})
  .bind('fileuploadfail', function(){})
});
```

**3** individual templates can be passed on the forms as attributes.

```
<form ...
  data-upload-template-id="template-upload-1"
  data-download-template-id="template-download-1">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. I tried to implement your suggestion. In the link you pointed, it is mentioned to change in main.js. But I downloaded latest code and there is no main.js file. I have appliction.js file which contains code `$('#fileupload').fileupload({

    //    });` Can you please which js file I have to change?

Comment: then main.js is your application.js ;)

Comment: `$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({   });
       
    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        ......
    });

    // Open download dialogs via iframes,
    // to prevent aborting current uploads:
    $('#fileupload .files a:not([target^=_blank])').live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        .......
    });

});`

Comment: Above is the content of appplication.js. Which contains there functions for #fileupload. I need to make changes only in first function (as you mentioned in step 2) or rest two functions are needed to be changed as well?

Comment: Thanks for your support. I tried to create multiple instances with your steps but not successful. Can you please if possible provide me a working example for multiple instance. Possibly I am messing up with scripts files. Thanks again.

Comment: Please understand that even with years of experience I struggled a lot to get this uploader working smoothly on all major browsers with  adjustments to our needs. This is definitely no beginner task. I tried to guide you to the right direction, but the last things you need to do on your own. Even if it is not fully working. Please ask a new question if new problem arises. Please dont forget to upvote / green checkmark the answer if it helped you to answer your original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

Create 1 instance with id 'fileupload' (this is the input element's id).
The second instance should be with a different id (e.g. fileupload2).
also change the div's "progress" id of the second instance (e.g. progress2)
everything else could be identical between 2 instances.
use the api on fileupload (first instance) as you usually did (e.g. $('#fileupload').fileupload({ url: url, dataType: 'json', done: ........});

Then bind the change of the SECOND instance to the first instance (selected files will actually be uploaded through the FIRST instance). You can do it like this:

```
$('#fileupload2').bind('change', function (e) {
$('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: $('#fileupload2')[0].files })                                                                                                             });
```